Detecting multi-colored tables using OpenCV
I would like to parse a table using openCV and tesseract. I was able to find many good questions on stack overflow regarding this. However, I face an issue. that is, The table I need to parse is multi-colored. see:
table
Using OTSU Thresholding
Mat img = new Mat();
Mat imgGray = new Mat();
Imgproc.cvtColor(img, imgGray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Mat imgBin = new Mat();
Imgproc.threshold(imgGray, imgBin, 128, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY | Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
Core.bitwise_not(imgBin, imgBin);

I get this
which is not ideal for extracting lines in the table and then parsing it since some lines are while and some are dark. I would like to know how extraction of the table structure can be done for such tables which are multi-colored. Answers in python would also be appreciated

related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79307295/what-is-the-best-way-to-avoid-detecting-words-as-lines-in-opencv-linedetector
