What is the best way to avoid detecting words as lines in OpenCV LineDetector
I am using OpenCV LineDetector class in order to parse tables. However, I face an issue when I try to detect lines inside the table. for the following image:

I use
img = cv2.imread(TABLE_PATH)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

lsd = cv2.createLineSegmentDetector(cv2.LSD_REFINE_ADV, sigma_scale=0.6)
dlines = lsd.detect(gray)
lines = (Line(x0, y0, x1, y1) for x0, y0, x1, y1 in dlines[0][:, 0])

in order to detect line segments. However, the results are lousy. these are the lines it detects:

How can I make sure that words are not detected as lines. I cannot use hardcoded thresholds since they would work for one example but not for the other. Solutions in python or java would be appreciated

related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79306804/detecting-multi-colored-tables-using-opencv

and be sure to verify answers before rewarding them. not everyone who posts an answer knows what they're doing.

Use morphology or filter contours to remove the small green regions from the lines contours.

You got some lines detected, but that set contained some undesirable ones.
You could just filter the set of lines for line length. If you do that, you can easily exclude the very short lines coming from the text in that picture.
Implementation: that's a list comprehension, only including lines that are long enough. Write a predicate function that gives you the length of one line, then you can use that in the list comprehension.
That is independent of how you scraped lines out of the picture. the LSD is one, but there are routines based on the Hough transform too, which might fare better or worse than what you have.
You probably also noticed that your approach didn't find some lines that it should have. You might want to tweak the parameters you pass to your line detector. Or try another line detection approach.

Regarding filtering lines, that would need a threshold to be hardcoded. But i fear then it might not be able to generalise to all such tables. Ill try out the Hough Transform routine.

a robust approach would consider a table to be made of long intersecting lines, or short but colinear segments (in line with each other) rather than independent. -- all image processing involves some sense of the scale of the image. it's either implicit, e.g. aligned to legibility vs. 72/96 dpi displays, or explicit, in which case you would have to guess it from image content (text), likely requiring analysis at multiple scales. -- the size of cell edges vs. edges from text is probably a factor of 3-10 apart. even if your image's scale varies, I think a constant should cover that well.

you provided one (N=1) sample of data. you cannot expect us to give you solutions that work for unseen data we can't reasonably extrapolate to from the sample you've given us. provide more samples, then you might be gifted a solution that works on all of those.


What is the best way to avoid detecting words as lines in OpenCV
LineDetector

The problem can be fixed.
I suggest using cv2.HoughLinesP for line detection rather than for text.

maxLineGap = 41 increasing may result in undetected text.
You can experiment with cv2.Canny using higher index as well.

Snippet:
 #!usr/bin/env python3.12
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('i.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 21, 75, apertureSize=3)

minLineLength =0
maxLineGap =41
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi / 180, 29, minLineLength, maxLineGap, 7)
for line in lines:
    for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
        cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)

#v2.imwrite('houghlines5.jpg', img)
cv2.imshow("image", edges)
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

Screenshot:


Thank you very much for the answer. I feel that this needs hard-coding and I would like to avoid any hard-coding steps so that I can tackle more general problems. I tried it out on a few examples of similar-looking tables with different kinds of text and the results aren't very promising

I have tried out a few things but here is what I found out to work the best:

Extract edges from the table using Canny Edge Detection

Use a line segment detector on the edges found out using canny edge detection with 0.3 gaussian blur
Put these lines onto a new image and the find the contours for this image

get the bounding rectangles using these image

filter out the rectangles which do not include any other rectangles


maybe consider this approach. The processing would need to be different though
